# What does EE processing in peer review process mean?

Tags: paper-submission

I sent a technical paper for peer review at Manuscript Central and after 5 days the status is Awaiting EE Processing. What does this mean?

Comment: EE is probably Executive Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the canonical question, [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like) Since EE is probably executive editor (per Nate Eldredge), that means your paper has passed the initial check. An editor has also been assigned. The next stage is editorial assessment:

> The editors decide whether the paper should enter the review process or should be rejected directly, e.g., because it does not fit the journal’s scope or requirements on importance or quality. A rejection at this (or the previous) stage is called desk reject. The paper may also be returned to the authors for reasons other than rejection, such as to request more data or clearer figures prior to formal review.

That's the stage your paper is likely at.